# PhpSpreadsheet reading through multiple files in php

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to build multiple `xls` files using PhpSpreadsheet library in a `foreach` loop but instead of reading data it shows the file names only.If I use the same code for a single file it works. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__."/export.php";

        use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Helper\Sample;
        use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
        use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
        use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;

define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('INSTALL_FOLDER', '/combine'); //Script installation directory if any leave '' if in root
define('DAT_FILES_FOLDER','/CompactedData'); // .dat files folder where generated
define('MAIN_PATH', ROOT_PATH.INSTALL_FOLDER);

function checkIsAValidDate($myDateString){
    return (bool)strtotime($myDateString);
}

$datFilesPath = MAIN_PATH.DAT_FILES_FOLDER;
$getAllFiles = glob($datFilesPath . "/*.xls");
$content = null;
$content_data = null;
$rowKey = null;
$file_name = null;


foreach ($getAllFiles as $fileIndex => $getfileName):
    $rows = null;
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load( $getfileName );
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $rows = [];
    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() AS $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); // This loops through all cells,
        $cells = [];
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            $cells[] = $cell->getValue();
        }
        $rows[] = $cells;
    }

$filesDataComplete = array(
    "filename" => $getfileName,
    "fileData" => $rows
);
endforeach;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($filesDataComplete);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: out of curiosity do you need to read that xls files on server side, or you need to do that on front side (facing pages for clients)?

Comment: I am reading from the serve rside

Comment: There is no output in this example script, so it's not clear what you're seeing or expecting.

Comment: @IMSoP actually I am trying to marge all excel files into 1 file with the so I am storing all the files data into 1 array so that I can complete the next process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disconnect from the worksheet and also unset the variable to make it work like this

```
$spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($spreadsheet);
```

In your case you code will look like this

```
foreach ($getAllFiles as $fileIndex => $getfileName):
    $rows = null;
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load( $getfileName );
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $rows = [];
    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() AS $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); // This loops through all cells,
        $cells = [];
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            $cells[] = $cell->getValue();
        }
        $rows[] = $cells;
    }

    $spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
    unset($spreadsheet);

$filesDataComplete = array(
    "filename" => $getfileName,
    "fileData" => $rows
);
endforeach;
```

Comment: you can accept your own answer if it is solved, so others will take it as a solution. :)

Comment: Sure but my reputation is low at this time I can't accept it before 23 hours

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540205/phpspreadsheet-skips-first-sheet-data